# Woocommerce + Payment (PayPal) - Securely update order status + get transaction ID

Tags: php, security, paypal, woocommerce, payment-gateway

I am currently implementing the [Paypal Payment Gateway](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Gateway_Paypal.html) into my shop.
I added an return URL inside my paypal sandbox account.

Payment steps so far:

- Create an order
- Create a payment via `WC_Gateway_Paypal` class
- Redirect to paypal site login & process payment
- redirect to `return_url` on succes

Sample code:

```
function create_order()
{
    $order = wc_create_order();
    $product = wc_get_product(55);
    $order->add_product($product, 1);

    $address = array(
        'first_name' => 'John',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
        'company' => '',
        'email' => 'john@doe.com',
        'phone' => '111111',
        'address_1' => '',
        'address_2' => '',
        'city' => '',
        'state' => '',
        'postcode' => '',
        'country' => ''
    );
    $order->set_address($address, 'billing');
    $order->set_address($address, 'shipping');
    $order->calculate_totals();
    $order->set_payment_method('paypal');
    $paypal = new WC_Gateway_Paypal();
    $paymentdetails = $paypal->process_payment($order->get_id());
    return $paymentdetails;
}
```

In `$paymentdetails` I return the paypal URL where I redirect the customer to.

After successful payment the customer gets redirect from paypal to:  `http://mypage.com/56/?key=wc_order_59d24a26d4ccb&utm_nooverride=1`

Now I want to update my order. I know that I could just read the ID and the key of the order from the redirect URL, but wouldnt that be an security issue? If someone knows the ID or the key he could just trigger a `GET` to my site and update his order without actual payment.

Is there a better way to accomplish this? Or do I just have to use the `key=wc_order_59d24a26d4ccb` instead of the ID and be careful not to send the key to the frontend?

Also, I am not getting any `transaction_id`, `$order->get_transaction_id();` is empty after successful payment. Is this because I am developing on my local machine / with a sandbox account?

Comment: Are you just building this to learn, or is there any particular reason you don't just use the free [PayPal for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-for-woocommerce/) plugin?

Comment: I am building a ReactJS app without any wordpress theming, thats why I need to be able to call all the functions myself via ajax

Comment: I think this is because you are developing on a local machine. Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likey because you are developing on a local machine.

The paypal integration does a lot of stuff in the background (exchanging tokens, updating orders, etc...). When you create a payment, paypal gets your local dev URL (i.e. `http://localhost/something`) but cannot reach it because you are behind a router. Try to move the installation to a server or webspace and try again, it should work.